# Any ways to give string input for the Stanford-parser DocumentPreprocessor class?

Tags: java, stanford-nlp

I'm trying to use Stanford NLP Parser which 
parses document into set of sentences. 
It reads filename which contains multiple sentences 
as an argument of the class, DocumentPreprocessor 
and then outputs parsed sentences.
However, I want to give inputs string by string which contains set of sentences but whole file that contains bunch of sentences.

Any ways I can do that?

Current program looks like below (https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/tokenizer.shtml)

```
public class TokenizerDemo {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    for (String arg : args) {
      // option #1: By sentence.
      DocumentPreprocessor dp = new DocumentPreprocessor(arg);
      for (List<HasWord> sentence : dp) {
        System.out.println(sentence);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you use buffered reader when constructing the object? https://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/process/DocumentPreprocessor.html

Comment: feed it with a `StringReader`: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/io/StringReader.html